Is there any multiple private keys for a single address wihin first 2^160 private keys?
There are three different terms:
Ethereum private keys are 32 bytes
Ethereum public keys are 64 bytes
Ethereum addresses are 20 bytes
So, it is possible of havng multiple private keys (2^96) for a single address.
Reson is very simple
Private keys are 32 bytes. So possible private keys = 2^(32x8)  = 2^256
Address are 20 bytes. So possible private keys = 2^(20x8)  = 2^160
So one address has =  (2^256 / 2^160 ) = 2^96  Private keys
My question is - Is there any multiple private keys for a single address wihin first  2^160 private keys?

Yes, there can be any multiple private keys for a single address
You can refer to this answer on Bitcoin StackExchange.
So, within the first 2^160 private keys, the likelihood of finding multiple private keys that map to the same Ethereum address is negligible. Cryptographic hash functions (like keccak256) are designed to make such collisions highly improbable within any reasonably large subset of the key space. Thus, while mathematically possible, practically it’s extremely unlikely to encounter such a collision.
Simplified Example Demonstration
Private Keys:
Let's consider private keys from 0 to 255 (in binary, 00000000 to 11111111).
Hash Function:
Assume a simple hash function where the hash of the private key is just the private key itself (for simplicity).
Address Derivation:
The address is the last 4 bits of the private key.
Here’s how the addresses are derived:

In this example:
Both private keys 00000000 (0) and 00010000 (16) map to the same address 0000.
Both private keys 00000001 (1) and 00010001 (17) map to the same address 0001.
Real Ethereum Example
In the real Ethereum system, due to the enormous size of the key space (2^256 private keys and 2^160 addresses), finding two private keys that produce the same Ethereum address through brute force or any other means is practically impossible with current computational capabilities.
If you were to attempt this in Ethereum, you would need:

A list of 2^160 private keys.
To hash each one to find their corresponding addresses.
To compare addresses to find collisions.

This task is infeasible due to the astronomical number of computations required.

Is there any example of one address having multiple private key?

I've added an example and a bit more supporting explanation.

Due to the nature of hash function output entropy, this problem is equivalent to asking about the probability of two random numbers in the range almost 0...2^256 falling within 0...2^160.
It should be 1/2^192 for one specific address, but we have 2^160 addresses, so the final probability should be:
2^160 / 2^192 = 1 / 2^32

So, there is 1 chance in 4 billion that one of the wallets will have at least two of their private keys in the range
0...2^160.
